# Allowing only few websites to AD group isng squid and squidguard on pfsense

Tags: active-directory, squid, pfsense

I wonder is there a way to block websites based on AD group criteria.
Say I have Students group in AD, and the users of this group can use any computer to login as I use roaming profiles. I want to make sure that users in this group will be able to access only the websites I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set authentication in pfSense in the
`Services->Proxy server->Auth settings->Authentication method` to NT-domain and fill appropriately fields related to NT-domain/LDAP  then `squid` should pull credentials from Active Directory

Comment: it can't be used with transparent proxy tough

Comment: Yes, it should be proxy with authorization and common web ports 80,443,8080 should be blocked in firewall for outgoing connections. This way no one can bypass your proxy